# How to implement a git client?

Tags: git, qt

I need to implement a git client. Basically i want to integrate git to an IDE. Same way as XCode and many other popular IDEs do that. I am working in Qt and QtScript. Now I need some pointers. My first idea was to execute terminal commands from inside my IDE code using a process and read the output. I was successful in executing commands and read the output but it isn't a good idea I think because it will be too much effort to extract information from the output.

My guess is that all the useful information related to git is available in .git folder present at the root of a repository. So I have two questions:

So what is the best way to integrate git support inside an IDE? Should I use a process to execute terminal commands and read the output or should i fetch the information from .git folder?

Are there some book or some tutorial that can be helpful for me in this regard. I am already trying to go through code of git.js. Lets see if it can help me out.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034962/which-language-has-the-best-git-api-bindings

Answer (score 2):

> Are there some book or some tutorial that can be helpful for me in this regard.

*Pro Git* has a [chapter dedicated to the "plumbing" of Git](http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-1.html), i.e. the commands specifically designed to be called by other programs.

Alternatives are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4036822/166749).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps check out some existing Git IDE plugins; see how they did it?

Eclipse: http://www.eclipse.org/egit/developers/

Netbeans: http://nbgit.org/

Notepad++: http://forum.lowyat.net/topic/1358320/all