# GitPython equivalent command

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I need a GitPython equivalent command or commands of this `git clone -b <branch_name> --recursive <url>`. I hope the subprocess call is not the only way to do this. If anybody have an idea please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`clone(path, progress=None, **kwargs)`](https://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=clone#git.repo.base.Repo.clone) accepts `kwargs` which are passed on to the call of `git clone`:

> - odbt = ObjectDatabase Type, allowing to determine the object database implementation used by the returned Repo instance
> - All remaining keyword arguments are given to the git-clone command

So you just add the options to your call to `clone`:

```
repo.clone(path, b=branch_name, recursive=url)
```

Comment: GitPython uses itself subprocess calls : https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/master/git/cmd.py#L17

Answer (score -1):

Git it self doesn't provide you with bindings for any programming languages (not even C). Libgit is one implementation of git as a library to be used in C. They are bindings to that library for many languages (see [Which language has the best Git API Bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034962/which-language-has-the-best-git-api-bindings)).

[PyGit](https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2) seems to be one that is maintained and works on git

Comment: [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython) (which is what the OP is asking about) is a Python module for interacting with Git repositories.